# How to compare two lists and change one property from one list?

Tags: c#

I have two lists. I want to compare two lists and change the `Selected` bool property `false` to `true` from `firstInstance`  if the `selectedInstance`  list items should have in the `firstInstance`  list. I have tried below code using `IEnumerator` but not getting as expected.

I am expecting the output:

```
 List<Data> firstInstance = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data { AccountNo = 1001,AccountName="AccountName1",BranchName="BranchName1", Selected = false },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1101,AccountName="AccountName2",BranchName="BranchName2", Selected = true},
        new Data { AccountNo = 1051,AccountName="AccountName3",BranchName="BranchName3", Selected = false },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1991,AccountName="AccountName4",BranchName="BranchName4", Selected = true},
        new Data { AccountNo = 1234,AccountName="AccountName5",BranchName="BranchName5", Selected = false },
    };
```

I have tried below code:-

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    List<Data> firstInstance = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data { AccountNo = 1001,AccountName="AccountName1",BranchName="BranchName1", Selected = false },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1101,AccountName="AccountName2",BranchName="BranchName2", Selected = false },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1051,AccountName="AccountName3",BranchName="BranchName3", Selected = false },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1991,AccountName="AccountName4",BranchName="BranchName4", Selected = false },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1234,AccountName="AccountName5",BranchName="BranchName5", Selected = false },
    };

    List<Data> selectedInstance = new List<Data>
    {
         new Data { AccountNo = 1991,AccountName="AccountName4",BranchName="BranchName4", Selected = true },
        new Data { AccountNo = 1101,AccountName="AccountName2",BranchName="BranchName2", Selected = true }
    };

        firstInstance.CheckActive(selectedInstance);
    }

    static void CheckActive(this List<Data> firstInstance, List<Data> selectedInstance)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<Data> firstEnumerator = firstInstance.GetEnumerator(), secondEnumerator = selectedInstance.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!firstEnumerator.MoveNext() || !secondEnumerator.MoveNext()) break;
                if (firstEnumerator.Current.AccountNo == secondEnumerator.Current.AccountNo) firstEnumerator.Current.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Data
{
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You told us what you want to do. You've shown us some code. What's the actual problem?

Comment: *"I want to compare two lists"*. How? Describe the comparison you want to perform. *"if the firstInstance  list items should have in the selectedInstance  list"*. How do you know whether it should or shouldn't? You need to provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: @jmcilhinney please check once. I have modified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to set the `Selected` property to `true` for all items in the first list which match with the second list, that only contains selected items?

Then this `Join` approach is efficient and works:

```
var query = from activeData in selectedInstance
            join allData in firstInstance 
            on activeData.AccountNo equals allData.AccountNo 
            select allData;

foreach(Data selectedData in query)
{
    selectedData.Selected = true;
}
```

Your approach does not work because you stop enumeration if one list is at the end. But you have to enumerate the other list(which contains all data) until end. You also have to compare each item with all other items, not just at the same index.

Comment: what is the different between your and @Rufus L's answer? can you please clarify me. Excuse me! I think Rufus L's answer is more readable? Am I right?

Comment: @Abhishek: Rufus `Where...Any` approach is like a loop in a loop that searches the first item that is Selected for every item in the first list. My approach is linking every item in the fist list that matches with the SelectedList. If the lists are small, choose Rufus because it's indeed more readable. If they are large my approach is more efficient since `Join` uses a set based approach(lookup performance similar to a `Dicitonary` or HashSet).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd need both enumerators iterating together. The collections' size doesn't seem to match.

I would do something much simpler:

```
var selectedAccounts = selectedInstance.Select(d => d.AccountNo).ToList();
foreach (var selected in firstInstance.Where(d => selectedAccounts.Contains(d.AccountNo)))
{
    selected.Selected = true;
}
```

This is assuming you are not trying to account for performance and big data structures.

Comment: No dear , we are assuming around 200 records in the list. is the loop become show the program?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to find all the instances in `firstInstance` where the `AccountNo` of the item matches the `AccountNo` of `Any` of the items in the `selectedInstance` list, and set the `Selected` property of those items to `true` in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in firstInstance.Where(first => 
    selectedInstance.Any(selected => selected.AccountNo == first.AccountNo)))
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit this line of code:

```
   // firstInstance.CheckActive(selectedInstance);
    CheckActive(firstInstance,selectedInstance)
```

and use this function...

```
    public static void CheckActive(List<Data> firstInstance, List<Data> selectedInstance)
    {
        var result = firstInstance.Where(y => selectedInstance.Any(z => z.AccountNo == y.AccountNo)).ToList();
        foreach (var _item in firstInstance)
        {
            if (result.Any(z => z.AccountNo == _item.AccountNo))
            {
                _item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `result` object is already filtering matching list of data then why do you checking again in side the `if` condition like `result.Any(z => z.AccountNo == _item.AccountNo)` ?